# C# - Automapper with Custom Type Conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, automapper

I am trying to map a request object to domain, and I can read English but I definitely can't find the solution in the automapper documentation.

**Problem:**


How can I map the ContainedEvent object from source to a derived class in destination object based on the EventType attribute in ContainedEvent object, because Event is an abstract class.
So let's say EventType == 1 in the source object, then Event attribute should be converted to one of its derived classes. I also don't want to map the null attributes but I handled that.

This is the request object

```
public class CreatePostRequest
    {

        public long EventTime { get; set; }

        public List<IFormFile>? Pictures { get; set; }

        public ContainedEvent Event { get; set; }

        public virtual List<string>? Tags { get; set; }
    }   

    public class ContainedEvent
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        #nullable enable
        public string? Requirements { get; set; }
        public int? Slots { get; set; }
        public double? EntrancePrice { get; set; }
        public int EventType { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the domain object

```
 public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime EventTime { get; set; }

        public Location Location { get; set; }

        public int LocationId { get; set; }

        public AppUser User { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public Event Event { get; set; }

        public int EventId { get; set; }

        #nullable enable
        public IEnumerable<string>? Pictures { get; set; }

        #nullable enable
        public virtual List<PostTags>? Tags { get; set; }
   }
 public abstract class Event
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Description{ get; set; }

        public string? Requirements { get; set; }

        public Post? Post { get; set; }
    }
```

This is what I am stuck at..

```
 public class RequestToDomainProfile : Profile
    {
        public RequestToDomainProfile()
        {
             CreateMap<CreatePostRequest, Post>()
                 .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));

        }
    }
```

Comment: Because there's nothing built in to help. _You_ have to write the code to choose the derived class based on the discriminator. Research previous solutions.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu should I avoid automapper for these kind of uses cases?

Comment: No, unless you have another mapper that does it better. But this is just one use case. AM maps are cached by types, that's why AM inheritance is based on the source type, not on a discriminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to store all Event implementation in context.Items, and provide a selector in the mapping.

Did not tested it but should be something like this

When you create your map :

```
CreateMap<CreatePostRequest, Post>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Event, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest, destMember, context) => 
        { 
            if(src.Event.EventType == 1)
            {
                return context.Items["EventImplementation1"];
            }

            if(src.Event.EventType == 2)
            {
                return context.Items["EventImplementation2"];
            } 

            // ...
        }));
```

When you map your object :

```
Post p = _mapper.Map<CreatePostRequest, Post>(postRequest, opts => 
    { 
        opts.Items["EventImplementation1"] = new YourFirstEventImplementation(); 
        opts.Items["EventImplementation2"] = new YourSecondEventImplementation(); 
        // ...
    });
```

Comment: This is kinda what I was looking for, a workaround :)